# Accidentally hidden vertices of BezierCurve - How to get it back?

Tags: 3d-view, bezier-curves

For some reason the handles on my bezier curve are missing. I probably hid them accidentally.

How do I get them back?

[image: handle.missing.bezier]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> unhides all of the stuff you hid in the current mode.  Or from the menu *Curve* -> *Show/Hide* -> *Reveal Hidden*.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/show_hide.html

Comment: Thank you, solved!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in the *Viewport Overlays* enable *Handles > Selected*:

[image]